# possible to set fake screen-resolution and browser size in webkit browsers?

Tags: javascript, c#, webkit, screen-resolution, awesomium

I want to know is it possible to set custom resolution and browser size in browsers based on `webkit` with anyway ( `javascript` or programmatically ) in my case i try to set in `awesomium`.

more description :

While browsing the web, I need to set fake screen resolution to any websites. for example if I load a site in full screen mode which has `1920x1080px` resolution I want that site think my screen size is `700x800px` and my browser size is `500x500px` or something else but still be able to browse in full screen mode.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/683873/faking-screen-resolution-given-to-website) for `Firefox`, `chrome` and `IE` I want something like them in `web-kit` or `awesomium` and access to that option programmatically. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

click the phone+tablet icon in chrome dev tools to enter device emulation mode. You can then enter custom sizes. It should work fine in fullscreen. You cannot do this programatically.